# How do I run jQuery plugins with Meteor 0.8 (Blaze) on template changes?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am aware of [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789821/meteor-0-8-blaze-how-to-update-rendered-changes-for-jquery-plugins) but I can't wrap my head around my corner case. In my situation, I need run those jQuery plugins unconditionally as I can't narrow down the potentially affected DOM nodes. My old code looked like this:

```
Template.Main.rendered = function() {
  jQuery('time.timeago').timeago();
}
```

But with the new layout engine the rendered events won't "bubble up" to my Main template which means that timestamps won't be updated to human readable representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found a very fine approach at [Meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Blaze_Notes#Template%20Helpers). No idea why I didn't think of it ...

```
<template name="TimeAgo">
  <time class="timeago" datetime="{{this}}" title="{{this}}">{{this}}</time>
</template>

Template.TimeAgo.rendered = function() {
  this.$('time.timeago').timeago();
}
```